# google chart candlestick colors

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to customize candlecharts from google charts.

I have found how to change the color of the candle themselves, but not the one of the line indicating the highest and lowest value:

[image]

Those are the options I provided:

```
    let options = {
      legend: 'none',
      candlestick: {
        risingColor: {stroke: '#4CAF50', fill: 'white'},
        fallingColor: {stroke: '#F44336'}
      }
    }
```

You can try it on this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/h5p36t3w/2/

I can't find in the documentation how to change it, does someone have an idea? (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart)

Comment: I have the same problem but I need these lines to be red or green, according to rising and falling colors. I think API doesnt make it possible :|

Comment: Hi, you should post a new question, I can't find anything in the documentation to resolve your problem...

Comment: I know, I think its just not possible and this lib is not open source, so I will look for apternatives

Comment: You could look at the d3 js library, I think google uses it under the hood. Its API is not the easiest one tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want all the lines to be the same color,
you can use the `colors` option...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
    // Treat first row as data as well.
  ], true);

  var options = {
    legend:'none',
    candlestick: {
      risingColor: {stroke: '#4CAF50', fill: 'white'},
      fallingColor: {stroke: '#F44336'}
    },
    colors: ['magenta']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using jQuery for other stuff and still no official solutions (afaik) from Google, I ended up with this:

```
jQuery('div[id*="chart_div"] svg g g[clip-path] g:nth-of-type(3) g' ).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('rect:first-of-type').attr('fill',jQuery(this).find('rect:nth-of-type(2)').attr('fill'));
});
```

(Please note the official examples have only one chart, mine page has several, hence each one has a unique id like chart_div_uniqueid, so evertything wrapped into a .each.)